# Emails are not sending?

Tags: apex, trigger

in my requirement if any duplicate lead is created send email to lead owner 
code executed successfully but emails are not sending , what is the problem ?
my trigger

```
trigger LeadCategory on Lead (before insert) {
    LeadVerification.duplicate(trigger.new);
}
```

and my class is

```
public class LeadVerification {   
public Static void duplicate(List<Lead> leads){
   List<messaging.Email> emails=new List<messaging.Email>();
    List<Lead> upd=new List<Lead>();
    List<Lead> totalLeads=[select Company,Email,Phone,Industry,OwnerId,Owner.Name,owner.Email,LastModifiedDate from Lead];
    for(Lead l1:leads){
        for(Lead l2:totalLeads){
            if(l1.Company==l2.Company && l1.Email==l2.Email && l1.Phone==l2.Phone && l1.Industry==l2.Industry){
                messaging.SingleEmailMessage email=new messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                string[] em= new string[]{l2.owner.Email};
                email.setToAddresses(em);
                email.setSubject('this is test');
                email.setPlainTextBody('this is verification of mail sending');
                emails.add(email);             
                l1.addError('duplicates record');
            }
        }
    }
    messaging.sendEmail(emails);
    }
}
```

thanks is advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not sending because you're using the addError method for every email you add to your email list. Remove that from your trigger and the emails will be sent.

**Edit**

You don't say if this is a before insert trigger or after insert, but I'm going to assume it handles the insert. Here's one way of handling things. You could also send `list dupes` to an external email handler class after inserting `toInsert`.

```
public class LeadVerification {   
public Static void duplicate(List<Lead> leads){
   List<messaging.Email> emails=new List<messaging.Email>();
   List<Lead> totalLeads=[select Company,Email,Phone,Industry,OwnerId,Owner.Name,owner.Email,LastModifiedDate from Lead];
   list<lead>dupes = new list<lead>():
   list<lead>toInsert = new list<lead>():
   for(Lead l1:leads){
        for(Lead l2:totalLeads){
            if(l1.Company==l2.Company && l1.Email==l2.Email && l1.Phone==l2.Phone && l1.Industry==l2.Industry){
                dupes.add(l1);
                messaging.SingleEmailMessage email=new messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                string[] em= new string[]{l2.owner.Email};
                email.setToAddresses(em);
                email.setSubject('this is test');
                email.setPlainTextBody('this is verification of mail sending');
                emails.add(email);             
            }else{
               toInsert.add(l1);
            }
        }
    }
    insert toInsert;
    if(!emails.isEmpty()) messaging.sendEmail(emails);
    }
}
```

Comment: if remove addError then duplicate leads can be created? i am avoiding duplicate leads

Comment: You need to detect the duplicate leads and remove them from your list of leads to insert (remove one or merge them into one lead). Once you add the error, you prevent the DML from executing. Email is a DML operation. You can do your duplicate lead detection in your trigger or another class, then send the emails to the owners in an email handler class.

Comment: thanks. got it.. is there any other way to achieve this ?